# Angular2 loading css styles dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have structured my application to both frontend and backend which contains two dfferent html templates.

I would like to load different styles when a user visits frontend and different styles when he or she visits the backend to maintain the already build html templates designs

THat is

In my index.html i currently have

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" ............... here i load frontend styles

       <link rel="stylesheet" ................here i load the backend
    </head>
</html
```

Now what i need to achieve is something like this

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" ............... *ngIf frontend

       <link rel="stylesheet" ................ *ngIf backend
    </head>
</html
```

or load the styles in the component like this

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

     ngOnInit() {
        //here load <link rel= ..... to the dom
       }
```

}

HOw can i achieve the above

Comment: Create two templates with its necessary CSS and use dynamic component loader. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#